# Should we "prefer composition over multiple interface"?

Tags: object-oriented, interfaces, composition

Should we avoid multiple interface if possible? Because I think at most cases a class with multiple interfaces can be replaced with another version with composition and single interface only e.g.:

multiple interface:

```
public class C implements A,B{
    @Override
    public void a(){
    }
    public void b(){
    }
}
```

composition and single interface:

```
public class ConcreteA implements A{
    @Override
    public void a(){
    }
}

public class ConcreteB implements B{
    @Override
    public void b(){
    }
}

public class C{
    ConcreteA a;
    ConcreteB b;
}
```

and if 2 interfaces have common parts, I can separate the common parts from the original class:

multiple interface:

```
public class C implements A,B{
    @Override
    public void a(){
    }

    @Override
    public void b(){
        a();
    }
}
```

composition and single interface:

```
public class ConcreteA implements A{
    @Override
    public void a(){
    }
}
public class C implements B{
   ConcreteA a;
   @Override
   public void b(){
       a.a();
   }
}
```

And even implement serializable:

```
public class C implements A,Serializable{
    String name;
    int userId;
    @Override
    public void a(){
    }
}
```

Actually I can wrap the Serializable part into a new class:

```
public class CData implements Serializable{
    public String name;
    public int userId;
} 

public class C{
    public CData;
    public ConcreteA a;
}
```

So my question is, should we prefer composition over multiple interface, i.e. : limit the class to implement at most one interface only , just like prefer composition over inheritance, if possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not really a question of which is preferred.  They are different solutions to different problems.

You would do this if a `C` ***is*** an `A` and a `B`:

```
public class C implements A, B { ... }
```

You would do this if a `C` shares some of the behavior of `A` and `B`, but ***is not*** an `A` or a `B`:

```
public class C {
    private A a;
    private B b;
}
```

This decision should be based on what the classes conceptually represent, not some notion of which approach is "better."

However, implementing many interfaces strongly hints at the [interface bloat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_bloat) anti-pattern, which is a violation of the [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).  A good rule of thumb is that if you can't describe what the class does without using the word "and", you're violating the SRP.